# ovsdb-tool: I/O error

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, syslinux

whenever I run the `openvswitch` script, the out is like

```
openvswitch            66388  0
vxlan                  37308  1 openvswitch
gre                    14162  1 openvswitch
libcrc32c              12615  1 openvswitch
```

then a few more lines and the end then

```
Compiled Mar 26 2019 23:03:08
DB Schema 7.6.2
  733 ?        00:00:00 ovsdb-server 
  802 ?        00:00:00 ovs-vswitchd
11757 ?        00:00:00 ovsdb-server
11760 ?        00:00:00 ovs-vswitchd
```

my question is what do these numbers mean. Is this an error or this is the part of script output.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 lts with kernel 3.12.74.